# Bash script to delete a file called index.html recursively

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, cron

I need a bash script (not sure how to write the actual .sh file) which I could set to be run by cron every minute and that would delete files with the name `index.html` that are in a specific directory and its subdirectories.

I believe that the following command will do that. However, I need to write it as a script file which I could then have executed via cron.

`find /path/to/directory -name "index.html" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf`

The `/path/to/directory` would be relative to the server root.

My two questions are, do I need a trailing `/` at the end of the path and how do I write the bash script file for example in a file called `deleteindexes.sh`.

I am assuming that I would need to set the file as an executable using

`chmod a+x deleteindexes.sh`

As regards setting the `cron` command, that is not a problem for me.

Comment: Which one do you want to delete by the way - `index.html` or `.index.html`?

Comment: that was a typo, should have corrected it. It is `index.html` and not `.index.html`. Corrected now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wouldn't even write the script -- you should be able to put the find command in directly. You can also call the delete command directly from find using the -delete action flag.

Step 1: edit crontab

```
crontab -e
```

Step 2: add in the following line (this will run it daily at 4:30am, change to your liking):

```
30 4 * * * find /path/to/directory -name "index.html" -delete
```

Step 3: Save and exit.

Comment: +1 but you do not need the quotes in there

Comment: @paulburkeland @zelda So the syntax would be `* * * * * find /path/to/directory -name index.html -delete`? Would that be recursive?

Comment: @alisamii yes, `find` is always recursive.

Comment: @terdon what is the difference between `* * * * * find /path/to/directory -name index.html -delete` and `* * * * * find /path/to/directory -name index.html -exec rm -f {} +`

Comment: @alisamii if you use -exec a seperate program is started (executed) for each file -> slower

Comment: @zelda is there a benefit to using the `-exec` that would make it preferable? The use case I have is related to a process which allows a user on a site to upload a pdf document. When a user uploads a document, a unique directory is created and the document is saved inside that directory. The process also automatically created a tiny `index.html` file it saves inside that directory. However, that file conflicts with a different process which automagically generates a link to the pdf on the site's front end, thus the need to delete the `index.html` file. Upload frequency is about 1 file per day.

Comment: However, it could be more frequent than that from time to time. Thus, I need to ensure that the `index.html` file is automatically deleted. I don't want to modify the process that generates that file, as the process will be needed elsewhere with the `index.html` creation retained. That is why I believe a cron process would be more efficient.

Comment: In that case it doesn't change much, you would only notice if you remove hundreds of files on each run of `find`

Comment: @Zelda I wonder if that's true. Since the OP is using `-exec command +` (note the `+`), that will cause `find` to combine the file names into as few commands as possible while `-delete` will call `unlinkat()` once for each file. I'm not at all sure which will be faster. In any case, aslisamii, these are details and you really don't care. Use whichever you prefer, just remember that `-delete` is not available on all `find` implementations.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned relative paths imagine that for example you want to clean up tree located in `/path/to/directory`. Then the following snippets will all achieve the same. The first one is using absolute path argument for `find`, the remaining three a relative one (relative to the one changed to with the preceding `cd`)

```sh
#!/bin/bash
find /path/to/directory -name "index.html" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cd /path || exit
find to/directory -name "index.html" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to || exit
find directory -name "index.html" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/directory || exit
find . -name "index.html" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Et voilà?

The trailing `/` is not important for the `find` command unless `/path/to/directory` is a symbolic link or you want to get an error if `/path/to/directory` is not a directory.

You will need to set the file as executable.

You just answered your own question :D

Comment: So, all that is needed to write a script file is to start the file with `#!/bin/bash` on its own line? That was simple.

Comment: @alisamii it can be `bash` or `sh` or `ksh` it depends on wich you like the most but for a simple script like this bash is ok

Comment: as regards the first cd command, please explain one thing. If I am looking to delete `index.html` in the following path `/home/user/site/client/conf/repo/section` and in all subdirectories such as `/home/user/site/client/conf/repo/section/dir1` and `/home/user/site/client/conf/repo/section/dir2` what would I put in as the path for the `cd` command and what would I put as the path for the `find` command. I want to ensure that it only deletes the files called `index.html` and only those that are at the root of `/home/user/site/client/conf/repo/section` and its subdirectories.

Comment: Also, would it be better to set the path relative to the user's home/root, i.e. `~/site/client/conf/repo/section` or relative to the server's root, that is `/home/user/site/client/conf/repo/section`?

Comment: `~/site/client/conf/repo/section` is an absolute path

Comment: ... because the `~` gets expanded to the value of `$HOME`

Answer (score 1):

A simple, fast and portable way is to use:

```
find /path/to/directory -name index.html -exec rm -f {} +
```

`-print0`, `-delete` and `xargs -0` are GNU extensions.

Comment: as you have `rm -f` I assume that is not a recursive delete. I assume I would need to modify it to `rm -rf` to make it recursive, right?

Comment: The `find` command is recursive. Unless you have directories named `index.html`, `-r` would be useless.

Comment: So, if I want to add it to the crontab such that it runs every minute, using `crontab -e`, the line I would add would be `* * * * * find /path/to/directory -name index.html -exec rm -f {} +`

Comment: That would be enough indeed.